# Cash Register lab using python

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner in coding, I'm having a problem with this homework where I have to make a Cash Register. You have to add a few conditions and my "Price after discounts" and "Total Price" are not giving me the right result.

**Write a program that computes how much a customer has to pay after purchasing two items. Make the lower-priced item half price. If the two items have identical prices, you can make one or the other half price.

The price is calculated according to the following rules:

• Buy one get one half off promotion: the lower price item is half price.

• If the customer is club card member, additional 10% off.

• Tax is added.

Inputs to the program include:

• Two items’ prices

• Have club card or not (User enters ‘Y’ or ‘y’ for “yes”; ‘N’ or ‘n’ for “no”)

• Tax rate (User enters the percentage as a number; for example, they enter
8.25 if the tax rate is 8.25%)

Program displays:

• Base price - the price before the discounts and taxes

• Price after discounts - the price after the buy one get one half off promotion
and the member’s discount, if applicable

• Total price – the amount of money the customer has to pay (after tax)
printed with the precision of 2 decimal digits.

Hint: In order to print a number in a specific precision, you can use the round
function passing 2 arguments to it.
Use help(round) to get a brief explanation of
this function, and try playing with it, to better understand what it does.

To format to two decimal places you can use the string format function with the format of 2.2f.
For example, an execution could look like this:

Enter price of the first item: 10

Enter price of the second item: 20

Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): y

Enter tax rate, e.g. 5.5 for 5.5% tax: 8.25

Base price = 30.00

Price after discounts = 22.50

Total price = 24.36**

***My code is:***

````
product1 = float(input('Enter price of the first item: '))
product2 = float(input('Enter price of the second item: '))
club = input('Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): ')
tax = float(input('Enter tax rate, e.g 5.5 for 5.5% tax: '))

taxes = tax / 100

print('Base Price = ${:,.2f}'.format(product1 + product2))

discounted_product1 = product1 * 0.50
discounted_product2 = product2 * 0.50

if club == 'y':
    if product1 > product2 or product1 == product2:
        cost_before = (discounted_product2 + product1)
        cost = cost_before * 0.10 - cost_before * (-1)
        print('Price after discounts= ${:,.2f}'.format(cost))
        print('Total price = ${:,.2f}'.format(cost * taxes + cost))
    if product1 < product2:
        cost_before = (discounted_product1 + product2)
        cost = cost_before * 0.10 - cost_before * (-1)
        print('Price after discounts= ${:,.2f}'.format(cost))
        print('Total price = ${:,.2f}'.format(cost * taxes + cost))

if club == 'n':
    if product1 > product2 or product1 == product2:
        cost = (product2 * 0.50) + product1
        print('Price after discounts= ${:,.2f}'.format(cost))
        print('Total price = ${:,.2f}'.format(cost * taxes + cost))
    if product1 < product2:
        cost = (product1 * 0.50) + product2
        print('Price after discounts= ${:,.2f}'.format(cost))
        print('Total price = ${:,.2f}'.format(cost * taxes + cost))```

**My result on this is**

Enter price of the first item: 10

Enter price of the second item: 20

Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): y

Enter tax rate, e.g 5.5 for 5.5% tax: 8.25

**Base Price = $30.00**

**Price after discounts= $27.50**

**Total price = $29.77**
````

Comment: you're not applying the half off on the lower priced item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only error is a logical one, found in the two `cost = cost_before * 0.10 - cost_before * (-1)` lines. If you look carefully you will see that according to this, `cost = 1.1*cost_before`. So you are not taking 10% off, you are adding 10%.

As that was the only error, and you profess to be new to coding, it might be instructive to look over the following, cleaned up code (not saying this is completely optimal either):

```
product1 = float(input('Enter price of the first item: '))
product2 = float(input('Enter price of the second item: '))
club = input('Does customer have a club card? (y/n): ')
tax = float(input('Enter tax rate, e.g 5.5 for 5.5% tax: '))

taxes = tax / 100
discount_rate = 0.5
member_rate = 0.1

if product1 > product2 or product1 == product2:
    cost_before = (product1+product2*discount_rate )
else:
    cost_before = (product1*discount_rate + product2)
    
if club.lower() == 'y': # cast user input to lower case to always compare with lower case
    cost = cost_before * (1-member_rate)
else:
    cost = cost_before

print('Base Price = ${:,.2f}'.format(product1 + product2))
print('Price after discounts= ${:,.2f}'.format(cost))
print('Total price = ${:,.2f}'.format(cost * taxes + cost))
```

Comment: Ty! I do have a question though, what does the 1 means on the part 1-member_rate

Comment: Just algebra. If you expand my expression out you get ```cost = cost_before - member_rate*cost_before```, which is logically what you want. The 1 simply comes from factoring out the common factor of ```cost_before```.